# Custom shape and animation with CSS3

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, css-shapes

Is it possible to create the following curtain effect with CSS3 shapes ?

[image]

[see animation example](http://rootcms.elocms.com/assets/images/www.vertuoz.fr/ex.gif)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried to make animation with border-radius and transition but i don't know how to crush circle from bottom and let the animation to be fluid (sorry for my english)

Comment: Please include the code you tried. There are many ways to solve a problem. If you want an answer, answers, suggestions, you must improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to place a circle on the left and a circle on the right. Each are animated to make an almost curtain expected effect (sorry for my english again).

```
<div id="animation-curtains">
    <div class="animation-curtain gauche wrap"></div>
    <div class="animation-curtain droite wrap"></div>
</div>

.animation-curtain {
    top: -60%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 1200px;
    width: 2400px;
    height: 2400px;
    background: #000;
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
     -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 3s;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}

.animation-curtain.gauche { left: -20%; }
.animation-curtain.droite { right: -20%; }

#animation-curtains.animate .animation-curtain.gauche {
    top: -200%;
    left: -85%;
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
}

#animation-curtains.animate .animation-curtain.droite {
    top: -200%;
    right: -85%;
    -moz-transform-origin: top right;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    transform-origin: top right;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
}
```